# Solving a Quadratic Optimisation in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, mathematical-optimization, quadratic-programming

I have an unconstrained quadratic optimization problem- I have to find u that will minimize norm (u^H * A_k *u - d_k)) where A_k is 4x4 matrix (k=1,2...180) and u is 4x1 vector(H denotes hermitian).

There are several functions in MATLAB to solve optimization problems but I am not able to figure out the method I need to use for my OP. I would highly appreciate if anyone provides me some hint or suggestion to solve this problem in MATLAB.

Comment: Does the index k play any role in your solution? Or is it just |u'Au-d| -> min for e.g. a given k?

Comment: no k is just an index,i.e i  have to min |u'A_ku-d_k| for k=1,2...180.

Comment: since you dont seem to have any constraints, you could just use 'fminunc'

Comment: Your writeup is not clear. Is your A matrix symmetric? What are the dimensions on A? Does k denote the dimensions on A? Or do you have to solve this problem 180 times for k=1 to 180? In the comment, you wrote |u'A_ku - d_k| which denotes absolute value but in the question, there are parenthesis. Which is it?

Comment: Yes, matrix A is symmetric 4x4 and positive definite. u'A_ku is a scalar and d_k is also scalar for a given k and eventually the OP is finding the vector u that would minimize: summation(sigma)from k=1,..180 norm(u'Au-d). (In latex the OP can be written as \sum_{k=1}^{180}(u^H\textbf{A_k}u - d_k))$$ but I dont know why it doesnt appear in this way here!)

Comment: Thanks. I can read latex code even if it isn't rendered. :)

Looks like a bit of a tricky problem to be honest. At first I thought it was a straight quadratic programming problem, but I think the norm or absolute value on the outside destroys the convexity of the problem?

Answer (score 2):

#### Math preliminaries:

If A is symmetric, positive definite, then the the matrix A defines a norm. This norm, called the A norm, is written ||x||_A = x'*A*x. Your problem, `minimize (over x) |x'*A*x - d|` is equivalent to searching for a vector `x` whose 'A norm' is equal to `d`. Such a vector is trivial to find by simply scaling up or down any non-zero vector until it has the appropriate magnitude.

1. Pick arbitrary `y` (can't be all zero). eg. `y = [1; zeros(n-1, 1)]`; or `y = rand(n, 1)`;
2. Solve for some scalar c such that `x = c*y` and `x'Ax=d`. Substituting we get `c^2 y'Ay=d` hence:.

#### Trivial procedure to find an answer:

```
y = [1; zeros(n-1)];   %Any arbitrary y will do as long as its not all zero
c = sqrt(d / (y'*A*y)) 
x = c * y`
```

`x` now solves your problem. No toolbox required!

Comment: thank you so much for your effort. Yes I have solved it by your method as well as by using fminsearch but I wish to do it in a "technical" way ;) So I am trying to solve it using Newtons-Ramphson method. I hope it gives a good estimate!

Answer (score 1):

```
options = optimoptions('fminunc','GradObj','on','TolFun',1e-9,'TolX',1e-9);
x = fminunc(@(x)qfun(x,A,d),zeros(4,1),options);
```

with

```
function [y,g]=qfun(x,A,d)
y=(x'*A*x-d);
g=2*y*(A+A')*x;
y=y*y;
```

Seems to work.

Comment: I appreciate your suggestion, but I am looking for a method that doesnt require optimization toolbox of MATLAB.

Comment: Since you have the function and the gradient, you could just implement your own optimization. Newton's method (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method_in_optimization) should work I think.

Comment: Yes, even I am trying to implement it using Newtons-Ramphson method. Is there any matlab built in function to compute the first and second order derivatives?

Comment: You have the 1st order derivative right there, its output g of qfun. Second derivative is also straightforward to compute from that.

Comment: I see. But shouldn't it be g= 2*y*(A)*x? (I didnt get the "+A' " part)

Comment: inner derivative is d/dx (x'*A*x), so chain rule applies, i.e. d/dx(x')*A*x+x'* d/dx(A*x)

Comment: This is a more rigorous treatment on the derivatives involved https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus